# Windows 8.1 Restart Prevention (Unrecognizable App)

Tags: windows-8, reboot

I hope someone can help with this issue...

I get a very unhelpful error message **intermittently** when I restart:

```
This app is preventing you from restarting.
```

There is no appropriate label for the application nor is there any legitimate icon - it's the generic icon for executables.

- What steps should I take to begin assessing what this application may be?
- Will you need any info of my machine other than the OS?
- Maybe a short list of the apps I generally am running?
- Or possibly an output from the command **`netstat -ano`**?

Thanks in advance